# Is it worth setting the site to run under TLSv1.2 or is the latter already bullet-ridden?

Tags: tls, openssl

From the perspective of investing resources into making the web services run under the protocol; does it make much difference whether you implemented TLS vs running in the plain HTTP mode inside the firewall?

Granted a vile presence made it to the intranet, how easy could TLSv1.2 be broken through.

Answer (score 2):

TLS 1.2 is probably still the best there is. Note that the idea behind the protocol itself is relatively safe. The problem lies within the details of the protocol.

There are several design decisions that are not all that great within TLS, like the idea of performing a MAC over the message / frames instead of over the ciphertext. The effect of that was that padding oracle attacks became a possibility. However corrected implementations of the protocol can avoid that. As far as I know there are no important vulnerabilities that cannot be patched.

As long as you keep your software up to date and choose a secure cipher suite and authentication method TLS 1.2 can still provide a lot of security. If it is easy to deploy then I would certainly not argue against it. If it is worth the cost is something that you will have to decide; it depends more on your situation (use cases, threat model, number of devices on the network, cost/benefit ratio etc.) if it is worth the cost in resources.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls are mitigations, they do not stop all attacks.  If they did there would never be any breaches.  If you value the data processed by your internal web servers then have them only use HTTPS.

TLS 1.2 isn't likely to be broken, but attackers don't need to break TLS, they go around it.

And don't think that firewalls don't have security issues as well, just consider this [vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20160210-asa-ike) in a Cisco firewall appliance, it allows remote code execution.  So, your firewall just became the attacker's firewall and he can then configure it to whitelist IP addresses he controls to further attack your network.